# Closure of the set $\{f\in C[0,1] : f(x) >0 \ \forall x\in[0,1]\}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $C[0,1]$ be defined with the max-norm and $A=\{f\in C[0,1] : f(x) >0 \ \forall x\in[0,1]\}$. Show that the closure of $A$ is the set $\{f \in C[0,1] : f(x) \geqslant 0 \ \forall x\in[0,1] \}$.

The closure of $A$ would be $A \cup \partial A$, but I'm not sure how to find the boundary here? It also seems that there would be alternative ways to show this?

Comment: Choose a convergent sequence $(f_n)$ in $A$ and show that the limit is in $A$. Conversely, let $f\in A$ and find a sequence from $A$ that converges to $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ then $f(x)+\frac  1n \to f(x)$ in the sup norm and $f(x)+\frac  1n >0$ for all $x$.

If $f_n(x) >0$ for all $x$ for all $n$ and  $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ in the sup norm then  $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for each $x$,  so $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Can you finish now?

[I am using the fact that a point belongs to the closure of  a set iff there is a sequence from the set converging to that point. Let $B=\{f \in C[0,1]: f(x) \geq 0 \, \forall x\}$. The first paragraph above shows that $B \subseteq \overline A$ and the second paragraph shows that $\overline A \subseteq B$].

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure what is $f_n(x)$ here?

Comment: I took a function in the closure of $A$ and wrote it as a limit of a sequence from $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the pointwise topology, $A$ can be seen as $(0,+\infty)^{[0,1]}$ and in this (product, essentially) topology the closure is $[0,+\infty)^{[0,1]}$ by standard facts about products (the continuous functions are dense in these product sets so that transfers to $C([0,1])$ as well). The max-topology is finer so we at least have $\overline{A} \subseteq B:=\{f \in C([0,1]]\mid \forall x: f(x) \ge 0\}$. The reverse follows as $B(f, r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ whenever $f \in B$ and $r>0$; balls taken in the max-metric, so that $B \subseteq \overline{A}$.